# jsPlumb choose which endpoint to connect to if an element has multiple endpoints

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm building a logic gate application connecting the gates via jsPlumb.

To create a logic gate end point I'm doing:

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint('and', {
        isTarget: true,
        maxConnections: 1,
        anchor: 'TopRight'
    },
    genericStyling);

jsPlumb.addEndpoint('and', {
        isTarget: true,
        maxConnections: 1,
        anchor: 'BottomRight'
    },
    genericStyling);

jsPlumb.addEndpoint('and', {
        isSource: true,
        maxConnections: 1,
        anchor: 'Left'
    },
    genericStyling);
```

This is all working fine for adding gates and inputs to the page and drawing the lines between them but I want to preload some existing logic using:

```
var left = getInput(logic.left),//adds an input to the page and adds a source endpoint
    right = getInput(logic.right),
    gate = getGate(logic.gate); //adds a gate to the page and adds source and target endpoints

if(left && gate){
    var leftLine = jsPlumb.getInstance(genericLine);
    leftLine.connect({source: left, target: gate})
}

if(right && gate){
    var rightLine = jsPlumb.getInstance(genericLine);
    rightLine.connect({source: right, target: gate})
}
```

but the connect function doesn't seem to pay attention to the existing endpoints and creates it's own.

How to I draw the connection between the input source and one of the gate's targets?

Comment: the code lives on a secure network and contains sensitive data so I cannot provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I found that this can be done by setting a uuid on endpoint when it is added and the connection drawn like:

```
jsPlumb.connect({uuids: [leftUuid, leftGateUuid]});
```